# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, css

My code is:

```
var body = document.getElementsByClassName("new");
var paragraph = document.getElementsByClassName("thisParagraph");
var backColor = document.getElementsByClassName("new")[0].style.background = "blue";

function typeColor(){
    console.log(backColor);
}
```

Comment: Видимо нет такого элемента. Покажите еще html

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего элемента с таким индексом нет.

Если 1000000000%, то скорее всего код запускается до того, как вся страница была загружена, поэтом надо использовать код после её прогрузки

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // вот тут код
});
```